# Does any API exist for Perforce that would allow me to register a call back to get notifications on changes to specific depot paths?

Tags: perforce

Does any API exist for Perforce that would allow me to register a call back to get notifications on changes to specific depot paths? I would like to avoid polling our Perforce repository for changes to specific depot paths and was looking for something like a web hook but I have not been able to find one. We are using classic Perforce (not git swarm or git fusion) with no streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perforce doesn't really have a "push notification" API as such.  You could potentially implement one within a `change-commit` trigger, which will execute on the server on a successful commit to a particular path, and can do whatever you want (so that could drive some other service you've set up that would implement the callback behavior you're looking for).

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.triggers.submits.commit.html